# Find a dropdown control in the last row of a repeater

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to hide the dropdown in the last row of my repeater control. I have used the following code, but unable to hide the dropdown.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="RpFilter" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpFilter_DataBound">
<HeaderTemplate>
<table style=" border:1px solid #df5015; width:500px" cellpadding="0">
<tr style="background-color:#df5015; color:White">
<td colspan="2">
<b>Advanced Filter</b>
</td>
</tr>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<table style="background-color:#EBEFF0;border-top:1px dotted #df5015; width:500px" >
<tr>
<td>
<asp:Label ID="lblField" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("COLUMN_NAME")%>' Font-Bold="true"/>
</td>
<td>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCondition" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Text="Equals" Value="Equals"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Not Equals" Value="Not Equals"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Less Than" Value="Less Than"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Greater Than" Value="Greater Than"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtsearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
<td>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOperator" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Text="AND" Value="AND"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="OR" Value="OR"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close"                
 class="fancybox-close" OnClick="btnCloseMsg_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search"                
 class="fancybox-close" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />

</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind:

```
     protected void rpFilter_DataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)

        {
            if (e.Item.ItemIndex == RpFilter.Items.Count - 1)
            {
                DropDownList Operator = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlOperator");
                Operator.Visible = false;
            }
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using it on the prerender event

```
protected void rpFilter_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Repeater RpFilter = (Repeater)FindControl("RpFilter");

    foreach (RepeaterItem item in RpFilter.Items)
    {
        if (RpFilter.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            RepeaterItem rptItem = RpFilter.Items[RpFilter.Items.Count - 1];

            DropDownList ddlOperator = (DropDownList)rptItem.FindControl("ddlOperator");
            ddlOperator.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

}

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it after the data has bound. In the `rpFilter_DataBound` event, the current row is always the last row, *at that moment in time*

Comment: After you have called DataBind, select the last item (excluding the footer) in the Repeater's Items collection, and use the same FindControl/Set visible method you already have.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to use condition

```
 if (e.Item.ItemIndex == RpFilter.Items.Count - 1)
```

Your code should be

```
protected void rpFilter_DataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
    e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)

    {

            DropDownList Operator = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlOperator");
            Operator.Visible = false;

    }
```

}